# Does Flatten have any effects other than flattening collections element-wise?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-flink, apache-beam

Specifically, does the `Flatten` PTransform in Beam perform any sort of:

- Deduplication
- Filtering
- Purging of existing elements

Or does it just "merge" two different PCollections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Flatten` transform does not do any sort of deduplication, or filtering of any kind. As mentioned, it simply *merges* the multiple PCollections into one that contains the elements of each of the inputs.

This means that:

```
with beam.Pipeline() as p:
    c1 = p | "Branch1" >> beam.Create([1, 2, 3, 4])
    c2 = p | "Branch2" >> beam.Create([4, 4, 5, 6])

    result = (c1, c2) | beam.Flatten()
```

In this case, the `result` PCollection contains the following elements: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6]`.

Note how the element `4` appears once in `c1`, and twice in `c2`. This is not deduplicated, filtered or removed in any way.

As a curious fact about `Flatten`, some runners optimize it away, and simply add the downstream transform in both branches. So, in short, **no special filtering or dedups. Simply merging of PCollections**.